# How to get back a decimal integer - java?

Tags: java, math, precision

So im trying to convert this equation : [10^(((level + 7)/2)^0.5)] - 100;

I do the following code:

```
  float A = (level + 7)/2;
  float B = (float) Math.pow(A,0.5);
  float totalExp = (float) ((Math.pow(10,B))-100);
```

If i input `2` for the level, i should get back 32.22706056. But Math.pow(A,0.5) returns me a double, so if level = 2, then A = 4.5, but i get returned 4.0 instead and similarly Math.pow(4.5,0.5) returns me a double, without the decimal numbers and throws all my calculations off. Hope someone can help here!

Cheers!

Comment: Double means ***Double precision floating point***

Comment: ah i see. So if i wanted to get back the decimal values, like 4.5 instead of 4.0 how would i do that?

Comment: Is `level` an `int`? If yes, then you're doing integer arithmetic. Make sure you are converting to floating-point before doing the calculation. For example by doing: `float A = (level + 7.0f) / 2.0f;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floating point literals in your program:

```
 float A = (float)((level + 7.0)/2.0);
 float B = (float) Math.pow(A,0.5);
 float totalExp = (float) ((Math.pow(10.0,B))-100.0);
```

Assuming `level` is an integer, `(level + 7)/2` is an integer expression that loses the decimals before getting assigned to a float.

Comment: Ah i see. So does it matter if level comes in as a double or float?

Comment: If `level` is float, your original code will work. Notice: I had to add a (float) cast to avoid a compiler error for the possible precission loss double->float.

Comment: yeah i see. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `100` with `100.0` or `100D`. Also fix the integer `2` similarly.

Comment: should the integer 2 be a double or float or doesnt matter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    float level = 2;

    float A = (level + 7) / 2;
    float B = (float) Math.pow(A, 0.5);
    float totalExp = (float) ((Math.pow(10, B)) - 100);
```

It will return totalExp = 32.22703